# plural of compound nouns

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, word-formation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the plural form of “iPad 2”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17366/what-is-the-plural-form-of-ipad-2)
>   [When can an adjective be postposed?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91664/when-can-an-adjective-be-postposed)

I'm curious particularly with iPod Touch and iPad Mini

The plural would be iPod Touches and iPad Minis, or iPods Touch and iPads Mini

Comment: Trademarked compound terms are exempted from the rules by law.

Comment: @JohnLawler What do you mean, is there a law that says how to form a plural of a trademark?

Comment: No. I was being facetious. I mean that trademarks are words owned by individuals and they can do anything they want with them. Including not follow spelling or grammar rules.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Touches and Minis. Not iPads Touch or iPads Mini. The plural is generally formed with an entire brand and model name. Compare Chevrolet Impalas (not Chevrolets Impala).

Comment: More often than not the last world is mean to be an adjective, in wich case wouldn't it be correct to make the plural with the word that specifies the object rather than its feature.

Comment: @rraallvv: Well, the skinheads in England referred to their "cherry reds" (boots) by pluralizing the adjective. And how about the double-adjective monicker [Black and Tans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_and_Tans)?